# Sharepoint pages with information from related lists

Tags: sharepoint

I have a site with a number of lists that are related through various lookup columns. I would like to create a page that shows items (from the different lists) that have a certain lookup value in common. What are the possibilities for this kind of thing in sharepoint 2013.

I guess I'm looking for something similar to a database select: "select * from listA, listB, listC where columnValue = "givenValue";"

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the content query webpart
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/When-to-use-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-or-the-Content-Search-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-346a0f48-38de-409b-8a58-3bdca1768929

This should still be valid for SP2013:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-data-from-multiple-lists-with-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-d560f477-8fc1-4258-aeb2-70aa932e07da